# Cloudformation YAML: expected type String, found JSONObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a template.yml in which I am trying to define this resource:

```
HelloFunction:
Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
Properties:
  Handler: handler.hello
  Runtime: nodejs12.x
  InlineCode:
    ZipFile: |
      exports.handler = async (event) => {
          const response = {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda function!'),
          };
          return response;
      };
  Events:
    HelloAPI:
      Type: HttpApi
      Properties:
        ApiId: !Ref SpikeApi
        Path: /hello
        Method: GET
```

The resources before this are created without problems, but here I get this error:

```
Properties validation failed for resource HelloFunction with message: #/Code/ZipFile: expected type: String, found: JSONObject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no need for `ZipFile` when using SAM. See the documentation of `InlineCode` here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-inlinecode